# MVC .Net Method Glitch or Gloat

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

A controller such as below can be used without any method prefixes (get,post,..)

```
    public ActionResult SearchNearAddress(string Longitude, string Latitude, string Address )
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This is kinda nice, because it allows me to use the same controller for all purposes (get and post) and saves me on code.

Is this poor design, or a nice feature?!

Comment: It would be a poor usage on your part :)

Comment: Primarily opinion based?

Answer (score 3):

If you specify your action like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchNearAddress(string Longitude, string Latitude, string Address )
{
     return View();
}
```

Then you only allow GET to occur. This is called an action selector attribute. There are others for the other methods (PUT, POST etc.).

By defining an action without them, you specify that your action should respond to any method.